# Select a random file from the file system

Tags: linux, files, performance, random

Is there a way to get the path of a random file from the *entire* file system (either from a single partition or everything under `/`), in a reasonable time?

Comment: file as in *any* file (hidden, directories..)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701505/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory-in-a-shell-script

Comment: In the general case, no. Find is probably the tool of choice since it case avoid the `argument list too long` issues but it can be slow. It also fails completely if the directory tree has too many files.

Comment: Possibly related [Random files selector in filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245105/random-files-selector-in-filesystem)

Comment: @doneal24, why would `find` fail if the tree has too many files?

Comment: @ilkkachu I have some NFS mounts with hundreds of millions of 7k length files in a small directory tree. `find` fails silently when traversing these trees. I've never investigated why, I've just avoided using find there.

Comment: Any file, yes. I was hoping there was a solution that wouldn't include traversing the directory tree. Like, picking a random inode somehow or pointing at a random spot  and finding a closest file or something like that.

Comment: @markonius, well yeah, the question then becomes _what distribution you want_. So far, it seems to me we've assumed you want all files to have an equal probability, regardless of their location in the filesystem. But you could start at `/`, randomly choose a file there, descend if it's a directory and repeat until you hit a regular file. That way you wouldn't need to traverse the whole directory tree, but the few files in, say `/root` or `/boot` would come up with a higher probability than the many files in `/usr`.

Comment: @markonius, picking a random inode would be nice, it's just that you can't find a file name by inode, and you can't access a file by the inode number only from userspace... Picking a random data block on disk would give greater weight to larger files, plus you can't really find which inode owns a particular data block without reading them all.

Comment: @ilkkachu  It's ok if I need root access. Could I interact with the file, for example, delete it with its inode, without its path?

Comment: @markonius, something like `debugfs` should be able to modify the inode data (permissions, owner, timestamps, data blocks) by just the inode number, or to create a new name (hard link) to it. But you can't find the existing names (hard links) to delete them without traversing the entire tree... (ok fine, it depends on the filesystem structure, so it might be possible in some filesystem, but I'm assuming something like ext4, where AFAIK it's not possible.)

Answer (score 1):

With `ls`, GNU `sort`, `tail` and file globing enabled

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -d /** | sort -R | tail -1
```

`sort -R` option is not specified by POSIX. It belongs to GNU sort's random implementation.

As stated in the sort man page

> ```
> -R, --random-sort
>     sort by random hash of keys
> ```

Comment: This dies with `Argument list too long` on most of my systems. In cases where it succeeds, it will print a filename but not the full path.

Comment: have you tried it?  its running for more than 10 mins and no result yet

Comment: @msp9011 See my updated answer. I guess that it will depend on many factors: filesytem size, CPU, memory, ...

Comment: This does not answer the question, e.g., give the *path* of a random file. It also depends on the alias of `ls` used in the answer. Finally, it takes 10+ minutes on a lightly-loaded small virtual machine and fails completely with a moderate number of files on the system.

Comment: Trying to glob _everything_ on the command line is bound to fail due to the argument size limits. Also, I wonder if `sort -R` is good here? It'll shuffle the _whole_ list, even though we need only one line. Though the pipe will kill it before outputting the whole list, but I wonder if it could still be optimized